# Variation in pressure for a gas phase reaction

Tags: stoichiometry

> Predict how the total pressure varies during the gas-phase reaction 
>   $\ce{N_2}(g)+ 3 \ce{H2}(g) \rightarrow 2 \ce{NH3} (g) $ in a constant volume container.

Reference: Atkin's Physical Chemistry, Tenth Edition, Chapter 20, Exercise 20A.1 (b) on page 870

My attempt at a solution: Assuming ideal gas behaviour we know that pressure is proportional to number of moles (volume and temperature held constant). Also, by observing the reaction stoichiometry the final pressure should be half the initial pressure as the no. of gas moles changes from 4 to 2

Initial no. of moles $n_i = n_{\ce{N2}} + n_{\ce{H2}}$ with no ammonia present.

at an arbitrary instant in the reaction $\alpha$ is the fraction of $\ce{N2}$ that has reacted.

So total no. of gas moles: $n = [n_{\ce{N2}}(1-\alpha)] + [n_{\ce{H2}}-3\alpha n_{\ce{N2}}]+ 2\alpha n_{\ce{N2}} $ ; the first two terms being the change in no. of moles of reactant and the last one being the no. of moles of ammonia produced.

This simplifies to, $n = n_{\ce{N2}} + n_{\ce{H2}}-2\alpha n_{\ce{N2}}$

What I think the question wants from me is a $P$ at an arbitrary instant given as a fraction of $P_i$ i.e $P_t= $$P_i$*[term depending on  $\alpha$]. Also substituting $\alpha$ = 0 or 1 should yield $P_i$ and $\frac{1}{2}P_i$ respectively.

For that, I am guessing the expression for $n$ should be expressed as a fraction of $n_i$.  However, I can't seem to think of the necessary algebra to obtain such an expression.

**EDIT:** Inspiration struck, what if I do the following:

$n = n_{\ce{N2}} + n_{\ce{H2}}-2\alpha n_{\ce{N2}}$

gives,

$n = (n_{\ce{N2}} + n_{\ce{H2}})(1-2\alpha \frac{n_{\ce{N2}}}{n_{\ce{N2}} + n_{\ce{H2}}})$

which is the same as, $(n_{\ce{N2}} + n_{\ce{H2}})(1-2\alpha .\chi_{\ce{N2}})$ where $\chi_{\ce{N2}}$ is the initial mole fraction of nitrogen in the reaction mixture

so, $n = n_i(1-2\alpha .\chi_{\ce{N2}})$ 
and consequently, $P_t = P_i(1-2\alpha .\chi_{\ce{N2}})$

Would this be a valid expression for describing the variation in pressure during the gas phase reaction described above?